# Why cannot use pointer of pointer as parameter to declare a function receive pointer of array

Tags: c, pointers

I have a c function receiving pointer of array as its one parameter.

Since pass an array is actually the pointer of its first element, so the pointer of an array should be a pointer of pointer.

```
int arr[]={0,1,2,3};
int main(){
    receiveArray(arr);
    receiveArrayPtr(&arr);
}
int receiveArray(int *arrPara){....}
int receiveArrayPtr(int **arrPtrPara){....} //Why cannot do this?
```

The Error message is

> "expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[4]’
>
>    void receiveArrayPtr(int**);"

Wish to know why

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Repeat : arrays are not pointers.

Comment: `int **p;` : type of `*p` is `int *` but address of array top is `int` value of `0`, not pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since pass an array is actually the pointer of its first element, so the pointer of an array should be a pointer of pointer.

That's not how it works.

*Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators*, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The type of the expression `arr` in the call to `receiveArray` is "4-element array of `int`".  Since it is *not* the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type `int *`, which is what the function receives.

In the call to `receiveArrayPtr`, the expression `arr` is the operand of the unary `&` operator, so the conversion rule doesn't apply; the type of the expression `&arr` is "pointer to 4-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[4]`.

This conversion is called *array name decay*.

Answer (score 1):

> so the pointer of an array should be a pointer of pointer.

No. *Arrays are not pointers*. *Pointer to pointer* and *pointer to array* both are of different types.

`&arr` is of type `int (*)[4]`. You are passing an argument of type *pointer to an array of 4 `int`* while your function expects argument of type `int  **`.

Change the function declaration to

```
int receiveArrayPtr(int (*arrPtrPara)[4])
```